# Python Limit time to run pandas read_html

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to limit the time for running *dfs = pd.read_html(str(response.text))*. Once it runs for more than 5 seconds, it will stop running for this url and move to running the next url. I did not find out timeout attribute in *pd.readhtml*. So how can I do that?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import os
import time
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen

headers = {'User-Agent': 'regsre@jh.edu'}

urls={'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058307/0001493152-21-003451.txt', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1064722/0001760319-21-000006.txt'}


for url in urls:
  response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
  response.raise_for_status()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  dfs = pd.read_html(str(response.text))
  print(url)
  for item in dfs:
    try:
      Operation=(item[0].apply(str).str.contains('Revenue') | item[0].apply(str).str.contains('profit'))
      if Operation.empty:
        pass
      if Operation.any():
        Operation_sheet=item
      if not Operation.any():
        CashFlows=(item[0].apply(str).str.contains('income') | item[0].apply(str).str.contains('loss'))
        if CashFlows.any():
          Operation_sheet=item
        if not CashFlows.any():
          pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what the issue is, but pandas seems to get overwhelmed by this file. If we utilize `BeautifulSoup` to instead search for tables, prettify them, and pass those to `pd.read_html()`, then it seems to be able to handle things just fine.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'regsre@jh.edu'}

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1064722/0001760319-21-000006.txt'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

dfs = []
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    dfs.extend(pd.read_html(table.prettify()))

# Printing the first few:
for df in dfs[0:3]:
    print(df, '\n')

                                  0   1                              2   3                        4
0                            Nevada NaN                           4813 NaN               65-0783722
1  (State  or other jurisdiction of NaN  (Primary  Standard Industrial NaN        (I.R.S.  Employer
2   incorporation  or organization) NaN   Classification  Code Number) NaN  Identification  Number)

                              0
0    Ralph  V. De Martino, Esq.
1           Alec  Orudjev, Esq.
2            Schiff  Hardin LLP
3  901  K Street, NW, Suite 700
4         Washington,  DC 20001
5         Phone  (202) 778-6400
6          Fax:  (202) 778-6460

                              0                               1
0  Large  accelerated filer [ ]          Accelerated  filer [ ]
1                           NaN                             NaN
2    Non-accelerated  filer [X]  Smaller  reporting company [X]
3                           NaN                             NaN
4                           NaN    Emerging  growth company [ ]
```